# Mysterious 2px difference between Firefox and Chrome

Tags: html, css, cross-browser, margin, background-position

My question is referred to [this](http://novaecomm.com.br/blog/) site I've been developing.
See the place where there are 4 circles and 4 buttons inside? This is their relevant CSS:

```
/* STEPS HIGHLIGHT */
.steps {
background: transparent url(img/bg-steps.gif) 37px 92px no-repeat;
    clear: both;
    float: left;
    text-transform: uppercase;  
} 
.steps .col {
    margin-top: 15px;
    text-align: center;
}
.col.steps-1 {
    width: 194px;
}
.col.steps-2 {
    margin-left: 40px;
    width: 196px;
}
.col.steps-3 {
    margin-left: 21px;
    width: 232px;
}
.steps .col.last {
    margin-left: 11px;
    width: 226px;
}
.steps .col.last h3 {
    margin: 0 auto;
    width: 129px;
}
.steps h2 {
    font: 24px 'ProximaNovaLight';
}
.steps h3 {
    color: #7f7f7f;
    display: block;
    font: 14px 'ProximaNovaSemibold';
    height: 20px;
}
.steps p {
    font: 9px 'Arial';
}
.steps .col .icon {
    margin: 28px 0 40px 0;
    position: relative;
    left: 43px;
    width: 98px;
    height: 98px;
}
.steps-1:hover h3,
.steps-2:hover h3,
.steps-3:hover h3,
.steps .col.last:hover h3 {
    color: #c03a2f;
}
.steps-1:hover .icon,
.steps-2:hover .icon,
.steps-3:hover .icon,
.steps .col.last:hover .icon {
    background: transparent url(img/ico-steps-hover.gif) -6px 3px no-repeat;
}
.steps-2:hover .icon {
    background-position: -240px 3px;
}
.steps-3:hover .icon {
    background-position: -457px 3px;
}
.steps .col.last:hover .icon {
    background-position: -700px 3px
}
```

As you can see I used a background-image for the circles and `<a>` elements to build the hover effect. Originally, the anchors have no background. On hover, they are assigned the same sprite and different background positions. I have used relative positioning and margins to position the `<a>` elements.

My problem is that there is a *2px difference* between Chrome and Firefox that is breaking the effect in the latter. I can't tell whether the difference is appearing in the margins ou in the background-position nor why it exists.

Did anyone have this kind of problem before? Why is this happening? How do I fix it? I've been struggling for hours trying to find a solution.

Comment: P.S: I still couldn't read through all your suggestions nor could I check them, I've been quite busy and the project's been put in stand-by for whatever reason. The problem wasn't fixed, though. I'll soon let you know if anything worked.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

May I suggest a better way of implementing this? You have 2 large images that are 21.8K and 23k. You only need 1 image for the circular background. and the icons with their red hover state in a sprite. and you don't need an image for the horizontal line, you can do it with pure CSS. Click on the link below. Here's what it should look like: [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/9YTAJ/3/)

your HTML:

```
    <div class="anchorSection">
        <div class="circle">
            <a href="#" class="wheel"></a>
        </div>
        <div class="circle">
            <a href="#" class="wheel"></a>
        </div>          
        <div class="circle">
            <a href="#" class="wheel"></a>
        </div> 
        <div class="circle" style="margin-right:0">
            <a href="#" class="wheel"></a>
        </div> 
        <div class="horizontal">
    </div>
```

and your CSS:

```
      .anchorSection{
            width:838px;
            height:102px;
            position:relative;
        }
        .circle{
            width:99px;
            height:102px;
            background:url("circle.gif");
            float:left;
            margin-right:147px;
            z-index:-1;

        }
        .circle:last-child{
            margin-right:0;
        }
        .circle a{
            width:39px;
            height:39px;
            display:block;
            margin:0 auto;
            margin-top:29px;
        }

        .circle a.wheel{
            background:url("wheel.gif") 0 0 no-repeat
        }
        .circle a.wheel:hover{
            background-position:-39px 0;
        }
        .horizontal{
            position:absolute;
            top:50%;
            border-top:1px solid #cfcfcf;
            border-bottom:1px solid #ececec;
            width:100%;
            z-index:1
        }
```

I have only done the first icon for you but repeated it 4 times. you obviously need need do the remaining 3 icons and their respective hover state. Make sure to put all 8 icons in a sprite, so you only load 1 image and use the proper background position to get the correct image for each icon and their hover state. Hope this helps.

Comment: In this answer, the hit area of the `a` elements is tiny compared to what it should be. Compare to the original website, where the hit area covers the entire outer circle (even on the site, it should probably also cover the text above the outer circle). There are a few other improvements that could be made to your answer, but they're not that important.

Comment: @thirtydot you're right. I have updated the jsfiddle to reflect this change with jQuery. http://jsfiddle.net/9YTAJ/2/ this can be done without jQuery by setting the height and the width of the anchor tag to the size of its parent. He can use the same technique for the area above the circles as well.

Comment: You can drop the jQuery and change the selector to: `.circle:hover a.wheel`.

Comment: ***I like this answer the best.*** While it's not the quickest fix, it does take care of better image management and flows in harmony with the webpage no matter the font-size or font-family. For this reason I've awarded the Bounty to you Sammy. Oh, and it's nice to see that your most recent jsFiddle revision `/3/` is done with just CSS thanks to thirtydot's suggestion, but using `/2/` allows for complex jQuery animations that may have not been considered. Cheers!

Answer (score 5):

In Firefox, the custom font "ProximaNovaLight" is not loading, so the height of the `h2` element inside `.steps` is slightly different to what it is in Chrome.

In Chrome, the `h2` has a computed height of 26 pixels, whereas in Firefox it's 30 pixels. Add this CSS to make Chrome and Firefox consistent:

```css
.steps h2 {
    height: 26px;
}
```

That's the quickest "fix".

The underlying problem is that the height of the `h2` *makes any difference at all*. The way you've implemented this part of your site is not robust. You have the whole "inactive" image as a background image on `.steps`, but then you have the "active" images individually positioned in each of the `<a class="icon">` elements. This is prone to breaking.

For example, even in Chrome where it supposedly works at the moment, try zooming in a bit and then hovering. The images jiggle around.

---

Another problem with the site is that you have a HTML comment above the doctype, which causes [quirks mode](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quirks_mode) (even [in Firefox](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/Mozilla%2527s_Quirks_Mode)).

```
<!-- BEGIN WP_HEADER -->
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN"
        "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
```

Remove the comment!

Comment: Regarding the `BEGIN WP_HEADER` comment: It doesn't have to be removed, it just has to be on the same line as the `<!DOCTYPE>`.

Answer (score 1):

Add this on your css:

```
* {box-sizing: border-box; -moz-box-sizing: border-box; -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;}
```

Answer (score 0):

OK. Downloaded all your resources and confirmed that the problem does indeed appear even in Chrome if the webfont isn't loading, just as it does in Firefox. (Simply deactivating the font in dev tools doesn't work for reproducing it because the element sizes have already been established by the time you do that.) So, we can answer "*why is it happening in Firefox but not Chrome?*" definitively with that: it's the font. So, if you can get your font loading properly in FF, problem solved.

How to fix otherwise? You are making your life more difficult by having the backgrounds be assigned to two different elements. (The main background is on `.steps` and the `:hover` background is on the `.col` child elements.) It's always easier to line things up when you simply swap backgrounds on the same element. I'd make the horizontal line the background on `.steps`, and then make the round badge icons both be applied to the `.col` divs. That way, regardless of how the rest of the page reflows, they'll still be aligned to each other, and at worst the background line will be slightly off-center. But...

But why is it happening here? As far as I can tell without being able to download your webfont files for further testing, it's because your `.steps h2` style isn't providing an explicit height and height is determined at render-time based on the font characteristics. When the webfont is present, that element has a height of 26px. When it's missing, the height is 28px. If you explicitly set the height to 28px, you can cover and plan for either situation. When I set that height to 28px, and then set the background offset for the icons' `:hover` condition to -15px instead of the current 33px, everything seems to work. When I make those changes on your production site in dev tools, it seems to work in both Chrome and Firefox, with or without the webfont.

Comment: You explained too many trivial points. It's better if you give the answer upfront, followed by one paragraph of explanation. One is enough in this case.

Answer (score -1):

Why not use a reset stylesheet to even out both browsers and then apply your styling.

http://meyerweb.com/eric/thoughts/2011/01/03/reset-revisited/

Comment: Just curious, why do you think resets are terrible?

Comment: I also dislike resets, but I do like [Normalize.css](http://necolas.github.com/normalize.css/). However, a reset is not going to help in the slightest here.

Comment: I, too, am curious as to why resets are terrible.

Comment: I, three, am curious. If it works and doesn't have any side effects why not? @thirtydot thanks for the link to Normalize.css.

Comment: Because resets are overkill (the entire point of normalize.css).